# How to open new form in specific time using C# winform

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a form, on button click event it is open. Now I want to open it on time basis of PC. when Time gets 10.00 in the morning then the form should automatically open within MDI parent. When Time gets 04:00 in evening then it should close automatically....

Please help

Comment: Have you done any research, or experimented with any timers?

Comment: I have tried so many times but unable to make it....... please help

Comment: Then you should post what you've tried. We can help assist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To manage time, you need to take timer control. Below sample code will help you to achieve your requirement.

```
public partial class frmStackAnswers : Form
{
    Timer tmr = new Timer();    //Timer to manage time
    Form childForm;             //Child form to display

    public frmStackAnswers()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Load += frmStackAnswers_Load;
    }

    void frmStackAnswers_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmr.Interval = 60000;
        tmr.Tick += tmr_Tick;
        tmr.Start();
    }

    void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Start child form between 10 AM to 4 PM if closed
        if (DateTime.Now.Hour > 10 && DateTime.Now.Hour < 16 && childForm == null)
        {
            childForm = new Form();
            childForm.Show();
        }
        //Close child form after 4 PM if it is opened
        else if (DateTime.Now.Hour > 16 && childForm != null)
        {
            childForm.Close();
            childForm = null;
        }
    }
}
```